# Convert __m256d to __m256i

Tags: c, type-conversion, intrinsics

Since cast like this:

```
 __m256d a;

uint64_t t[4];

_mm256_store_si256( (__m256i*)t, (__m256i)a );/* Cast of 'a' to __m256i not allowed */
```

are not allowed when compiling under Visual Studio, I thought I could use some intrinsic functions to convert a __m256d value into a __m256i before passing it to *_mm256_store_si256* and thus, avoiding the cast which causes the error.

But after looking on [that list](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Convert&text=__m256i), I couldn't find a function taking for argument a __m256d value and returning a __256i value. So maybe you could help me writing my own function or finding the function I'm looking for, a function that stores 4x 64-bit double bit value to an array of 4x64-bit integers.

**EDIT:**

After further research, I found *_mm256_cvtpd_epi64* which seems to be exactly what I want. But, my CPU doesn't support AVX512 instructions set...

What is left for me to do here?

Comment: @PaulR: I *think* the OP wants to store 4x 64-bit `double` bit-patterns to an array of 64-bit integers, without double->int conversion.

Comment: How about using a srtuct instead of those Intel specific intrinsic type?

Comment: There is no problem with the double->int conversion, that's no matter

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, you’re probably right - the question is not very clear.

Comment: @Biswapriyo What do you mean by using a struct?

Comment: I've not see the array. I assume that if you are using 256bit integer then it may be used with 4 x 64bit array or 4 member struct.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I'm not sure if such a struct would do the job of replacing special Intel's intrinsic types used in arguments for the intrinsic functions.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: A union like `union { uint64_t t[4]; __m256d vec; };` would be another option for type-punning with C, or for C++ with some compilers.  But it turns out the OP isn't looking for type-punning, they want to *convert* to integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **`_mm256_store_pd( (double*)t, a)`**.  I'm pretty sure this is strict-aliasing safe because you're not directly dereferencing the pointer after casting it.  The `_mm256_store_pd` intrinsic wraps the store with any necessary may-alias stuff.

(With AVX512, Intel switched to using `void*` for the load/store intrinsics instead of `float*`, `double*`, or `__m512i*`, to remove the need for these clunky casts and make it more clear that intrinsics can alias anything.)

The other option is to [`_mm256_castpd_si256`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=411,3941,3941,433,1508,408,5534,392,394,3116,5197,3169,5198,3117,3116,3116,5197,1662,4255,5240,2317,4494,4485,4466,586&techs=AVX,AVX2&text=castpd) to reinterpret the bits of your `__m256d` as a `__m256i`:

```
alignas(32) uint64_t t[4];
_mm256_store_si256( (__m256i*)t,  _mm256_castpd_si256(a));
```

If you read from `t[]` right away, your compiler might optimize away the store/reload and just shuffle or `pextrq rax, xmm0, 1` to extract FP bit patterns directly into integer registers.  You could write this manually with intrinsics.  Store/reload is not bad, though, especially if you want more than 1 of the `double` bit-patterns as scalar integers.

You *could* instead use `union m256_elements { uint64_t u64[4]; __m256d vecd; };`, but there's no guarantee that will compile efficiently.

---

**This cast compiles to zero asm instructions, i.e. it's just a type-pun to keep the C compiler happy**.

If you wanted to actually round packed `double` to the nearest signed or unsigned 64-bit integer and have the result in 2's complement or unsigned binary instead of IEEE754 binary64, you need AVX512F `_mm256/512_cvtpd_epi64` ([`vcvtpd2qq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VCVTPD2QQ.html)) for it to be efficient.  SSE2 + x86-64 can do it for scalar, or you can use some packed FP hacks for numbers in the `[0..2^52]` range: [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144668/how-to-efficiently-perform-double-int64-conversions-with-sse-avx).

---

BTW, `storeu` doesn't require an aligned destination, but `store` does.  If the destination is a local, you should normally align it instead of using an unaligned store, at least if the store happens in a loop, or if this function can inline into a larger function.

Comment: _mm256_castpd_si256 seems to do the job. Thanks

Comment: @TomClabault: oh, so the edit to your question is wrong, and you *didn't* want to convert to integer with `_mm256_cvtpd_epi64` or a non-AVX512 equivalent?  You just want to type-pun the `double` bit-patterns to `uint64_t`?  If yes, I'll undo the duplicate-close.

Comment: Yes, that's no conversion but type-pun from double to int