# How to convert 64-bit int to float on 32-bit PowerPC?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, powerpc

I'm writing assembly on a 32-bit PowerPC system (specifically, a GameCube). I have a 64-bit integer that I need to convert to a floating-point number. How can I do this? Examples I can find online all involve the use of `fcfid` instruction, but this is only available on 64-bit systems.

The code so far is:

```
CALL  __OSGetSystemTime # -> u64 ticks in r3, r4
stw   r3, SP_FLOAT_TMP(r1)
stw   r4, (SP_FLOAT_TMP+4)(r1)
lfd   f1, SP_FLOAT_TMP(r1)
fcfid f1 # u64 -> double
frsp  f1 # double -> float
```

(`CALL` is a macro for position-independent `bl`)

The GNU Assembler gives an error:

```
Error building debugprint debugprint.s: Assembler messages:
debugprint.s:345: Error: unrecognized opcode: `fcfid'
```

Comment: Related: x86 SIMD can similarly only do packed FP conversion to/from 32-bit int, not 64.  [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41144668) shows FP bit-pattern hacks that can get the job done efficiently for limited range inputs (+- 2^51) with a bitwise operations and an add or sub.  Also, compilers generally know how to do this, you can usually check GCC or clang output, especially if they inline the helper function.

Comment: clang and clang just call a helper function, `__floatdisf` https://godbolt.org/z/e6s1ax.  But you could look in the libgcc source for its implementation.  (But like I said, if you don't need full range inputs, you can use a more efficient way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used PowerPC since the early 2000s, so I will present C code that outlines an algorithm that I think will be translatable into 32-bit PowerPC instructions. The basic idea is to split the 64-bit integer into two 32-bit halves comprising the most significant and least significant bits, respectively. Convert each half to a `double` using the magic-number addition technique. Combine the two resulting doubles using a fused multiply-add (FMA) operation, scaling the high half by 2<sup>32</sup>. This incurs just a single rounding.

Because this is a conversion of unsigned integers, the magic number we need here is 2<sup>52</sup>. Construct the binary image of that number in memory, then place the 32-bit integer N into the least significant 32 bits. This creates the binary image of a `double` with the value 2<sup>52</sup>+N. Load that `double` from memory, then subtract out 2<sup>52</sup>, leaving N in the floating-point register. The result is exact.

I have annotated the ISO-C99 code with the PowerPC instructions I think one would use to code this in assembly language.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>  // for memcpy
#include <math.h>    // for fma

/* re-interpret a 64-bit unsigned integer in two halves as a double */
double hilo_uint32_as_double (uint32_t hi, uint32_t lo)
{
    double r;
    uint64_t t = ((uint64_t)hi << 32) + (uint64_t)lo;
    memcpy (&r, &t, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

double uint64_to_double (uint64_t a)
{
    const double two_to_32 = 0x1.0p32;
    const double magic = hilo_uint32_as_double (0x43300000, 0); // 0x1.0p52

    /* split 64-bit number into two 32-bit halves */
    uint32_t hi = (uint32_t)(a >> 32);         // stw
    uint32_t lo = (uint32_t)(a & 0xffffffff);  // stw
    /* convert each 32-bit half into a double */
    double lof = hilo_uint32_as_double (0x43300000, lo) - magic; // stw, lfd, fsub
    double hif = hilo_uint32_as_double (0x43300000, hi) - magic; // stw, lfd, fsub
    /* combine halves with a single rounding */
    return fma (hif, two_to_32, lof); // fmadd
}

int main (void)
{
    uint64_t a = 1234567890123456ULL;
    printf ("%llu -> %23.16e\n", a, uint64_to_double (a));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to convert that easily.