# Multiplying packed 32-bit integers by a 32-bit float with AVX2

Tags: assembly, x86-64, avx2

I'm trying to perform a float + integer multiplication without losing too much precision. In particular, my float, mean, is in [0, 1) and the integer, value, is any `uint32`.

Since float32 cannot express all uint32 values, my approach was to convert value to `uint64` in two 256-bit registers, convert both to `float64`, multiply, then, convert back to `uint32`. So far, I have something like (using [go-asm](https://github.com/mmcloughlin/avo) but hopefully still gets the idea across...)

```golang
    // first, convert mean to float64
    VCVTPS2PD(mean, Y3)

    // convert deltas to uint64 in two registers
    VEXTRACTI128(U8(0), value, Y1)
    VEXTRACTI128(U8(1), value, Y2)
    VPMOVZXDQ(Y1, Y1)
    VPMOVZXDQ(Y2, Y2)

    // convert to float64
    VCVTUDQ2PD(Y1, Y1)
    VCVTUDQ2PD(Y2, Y2)

    // multiply by mean
    VMULPD(Y1, Y3, Y1)
    VMULPD(Y2, Y3, Y2)

    // convert back to int
    VCVTPD2UDQ(Y1, Y1)
    VCVTPD2UDQ(Y2, Y2)
```

but then I can't seem to figure out how to blend the two registers back into one register. In other words, I can't seem to find the opposite of the extract operation.

Is there a better approach to this that I'm not considering as well?

EDIT: Some clarifications that came up in the comments,

1. Each multiplication (mean, value) is a distinct pair, not a broadcasted scalar multiplication.
2. The mean is calculated from some other float32's which are also in the range [0,1). The comments suggested using a fixed point for computation, this is a viable option if it's helpful. To be concrete, the mean is a probability and the operation I'd like is to bias the value based on a mean of probabilities, for which the calculation is beyond this question's scope.
3. I have AVX2 and FMA instructions but not AVX512.
4. Round to nearest is preferred as this operation will be done repeatedly so I don't want to introduce bias, but if truncation is substantially faster I am interested in the tradeoff. This code is used in an estimation algorithm so slight bias is not catastrophic as long as it's characterized.

Comment: Does that float input have to be a float, can it be a 32-bit fixed-point number in the range [0..1)?

Comment: `VCVTUDQ2PD` is AVX-512, and takes packed 32-bit integers as the source operand.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtudq2pd  .  x86 doesn't have unsigned <-> FP or SIMD packed int64 <-> FP conversions before AVX-512, see [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41144668)  (a zero-extended u32 can be treated as an non-negative i64 or u64 whichever is more convenient, so Mysticial's limited-range conversion works.)  Of course if you actually have AVX-512, using it with 256-bit vectors is much better than AVX2 for this.

Comment: You have one scalar `mean`?  That should probably be `vbroadcastss(mean, X3)` / `vcvtps2pd(X3, Y3)`, or `vcvtss2sd(mean, X7, X3)` / `vbroadcastsd(X3, Y3)`.  The former avoids any false-dependency problems, but the latter (memory-source scalar convert then broadcast) actually costs fewer port-5 shuffle uops on Intel CPUs (https://uops.info/).  Unless you can use AVX-512 broadcast memory-source operands.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry I should've made that more clear. I don't have one scalar mean, each value needs to be multiplied with its paired mean. Unfortunately I don't have AVX-512 though, so I guess my original strategy also wouldn't have worked :(

Comment: @harold I could use a fixed point number, would that offer a better instruction to use? I would, however, have to convert the mean from floating point if that makes a difference since the mean is calculated from other floating points which are not necessarily in the [0, 1) range.

Comment: With fixed-point you'd want the high half of a 32x32 => 64-bit multiply, so `vpmuludq` with odd and even elements and take the high 32 bits (like `vpsrlq` by 32 + `vpblendd` to recombine the results for even + odd elements of one input).  Maybe only worth it if you're reusing the same scale factors across more multiplies, to amortize the cost of getting the right fixed-point integer for each float.

Comment: You used `Y3` with two different vectors of int inputs; if you're trying to implement `u32_dst[i] = (double)u32_src[i] * (double)float_scale[i]` (C syntax), that's not right.  If that's what you want, have a look at how GCC and Clang auto-vectorize C++: https://godbolt.org/z/dWzYEsje4 .  (AT&T syntax has the same operand-order as Goasm).  You might be able to simplify some based on known range limits, e.g. that the resulting `double` product is in the 0..2^52 range since the multiplier is less than 1.0, so conversion back to integer can be cheaper.

Comment: Oh wow that tool is so useful. I'll use that as a starting point, thanks! I was hoping this was an operation that wasn't too complex and I was only missing something in the documentation, but I guess that wasn't quite the case.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question adding the clarifications you made in the comments? (E.g., that you have different scalings per element, that they need to be calculated as `float`, etc (do they actually? Just some elements being >1 does not rule out using fixed-point -- without more info it is not possible to say if fixed-point makes sense though)). Also for rounding the final result back to `uint32` do you prefer round-to-nearest or truncation, or does it not matter? And do you have FMA? (very likely, if you have AVX2).

Comment: I think the most efficient way is to split the source into upper and lower half and multiply them together with some FMA operations. I'll later write a full answer for that.

Comment: Thanks @chtz, I've updated the question. I agree on the split approach however it's tricky for me to write. I am new to assembly so learning from a more knowledgeable example would be super helpful!